# messaging.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification to an android device by sending it from a web app.

I tried to do it this way, but I get this error. I looked at many other questions but could not find an answer. I updated everything but it doesn't work anyway.

what am I doing wrong?

my code:

```
   const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    var message = {
       data: {
         score: '850',
           time: '2:45'
          },
       token: registrationToken
   };


messaging.send(message)
   .then((response) => {
     // Response is a message ID string.
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error sending message:', error);
   });
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of a `.send()` method in the Firebase messaging documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the Firebase Admin SDK, which has the ability to send FCM messages.

The Admin SDK grants its user full administrative access to your Firebase project, meaning that this code can send any kind of message to all your users, but it can also access any other resources (files, database, user accounts) in your project at will. For this reason the Admin SDK is only meant to be used in a trusted environment, such as a server you control, your development machine, or Cloud Functions. It is explicitly not to be used within web pages.

A typical approach to accomplish your goal is to create a Cloud Function that sends the correct message, and then call that Cloud Function from your web page. Since only collaborators on your Firebase project can deploy Cloud Functions, this way you can be sure that the message that is sent is coming from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use admin as meant in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#send_a_notification_message) apparently. To do that, make sure `firebase-admin` is installed, if not, run `npm install firebase-admin`.

And then use as:

```js
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    // Your logic here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: i try it, but i retrive in console: admin is not defined